# How to use C++ default arguments in the call command of gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

`gdb` doesn't seem to support [C++ default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) when calling functions with the `call` command:

```
void dbg_test(int a = 1) {
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

`gdb` says:

```
(gdb) call dbg_test()
Too few arguments in function call.
(gdb) call dbg_test(2)
2
(gdb)
```

I guess this is because default values are injected during compile time and
`gdb` is a debugger, not a compiler ;-)

Any chance to use default values in `gdb` anyhow?

**Edit:** Or do you know a reference that explicitly says that only the compiler knows the default values?

**Edit:** `gdb`s autocompletion (TAB TAB) only shows the data type, not the default value:

```
(gdb) call dbg_test(int)
```

Comment: maybe add `void dbg_test_default() { dbg_test(); }` to your code?

Comment: Ah, I know what you mean. Good idea :-) But let's suppose I don't want to modify the source code. I am not even sure if `gdb` knows the default values...

Comment: @Frank BTW: If I were modifying the source code I would even dare to overload the function (use polymorphism) to simulate a default value: `void dbg_test() { int a = 1; ... }`

Comment: Its not possible to know the default arguments of a function without having to modify the code, or knowing the header. Because the default argument will be generated and put into your code by the compiler.

Comment: Looks like not supported yet. [gdb: C++ Expressions](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/C-Plus-Plus-Expressions.html) says `GDB expression handling can interpret most C++ expressions. [...]  It also cannot handle ellipsis argument lists or default arguments.`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick GREAT comment, please post this as answer and I will accept it. THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if this isn't possible right now with the current versions of gdb, gcc, and clang.

The [C++ Expressions](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/C-Plus-Plus-Expressions.html) section of the gdb manual says:

> GDB expression handling can interpret most C++ expressions. 
>   
>   ...
>   
>   GDB does not perform overload resolution involving user-defined type conversions, calls to constructors, or instantiations of templates that do not exist in the program. **It also cannot handle ellipsis argument lists or default arguments.**

I wrote some tests and compiled them with g++ 9.2.1 and clang++ 9.0.0-2. In all cases, I did not see any DWARF information related to default argument values. And in all cases, the code to evaluate an argument's default value was within the caller's code, not the callee's code. So there appears to be no reliable way for gdb to discern how to evaluate an argument's default value.

[DWARF Issue 141117.1](http://dwarfstd.org/ShowIssue.php?issue=141117.1) may indicate that, eventually, there will be a `DW_AT_default_value` attribute that refers to a constant or piece of code or string of source code containing the expression that gets evaluated as the argument's default value.