# Cannot resolve function to any overloaded instance

Tags: c++, gdb, debian

I have looked into other answers to resolve this but no luck. So, here is the problem:

I have two functions

```
string vts(vector<int> ,/*default*/ bool = true,/*default*/ bool = true);
string vts(vector<string> ,/*default*/ bool = true);
```

During debugging, it seems like GDB is not able to resolve b/w the two functions for a `vector<int>`.

It throws following error

```
(gdb) call vts(v)
Cannot resolve function vts to any overloaded instance
```

where

```
v = std::vector<int> of length 5, capacity 5 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Invocation by passing all arguments also fail

```
Invokation
(gdb) call vts(v, false, false)

Output
Cannot resolve function vts to any overloaded instance
```

I have tried setting overload-resolution on and off but does not work. Any pointers to fix this would be helpful?

Comment: So your function takes at least 2 parameters, yet you're passing 1 argument?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The other bool flags are set as true by default in function declaration. Tho, I just tried by passing all arguments to vts, still the invokation fails

Comment: There are exactly 2 functions. Any defaulted parameters are created&passed by the compiler at the call site. Gdb doesn't have access to the header, so it just sees 2 possible matches for overload resolution taking 2 and 3 parameters respectively. None of those match the parameter list you provided.

Comment: @fabian I just tried so by passing all params. Yet, the invokation could not be resolved. why is that?

Comment: Not sure if gdb does consider creating a copy of the vector; if it doesn't this could prevent the second scenario from working.

Comment: @fabian It allows that. It only broke when I added another function `vts` with `different` set of `args`

Comment: Duplicate for the first part of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58827121/how-to-use-c-default-arguments-in-the-call-command-of-gdb

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I had to use the complete function signature to make the call complete.

```
 p 'vts(std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>,bool,bool)'(v,0,0)
```

The reported behaviour does seem like a bug in gdb.